# What are the full-text search tools you can use in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, full-text-search

Besides full-text indexing and using LIKE keyword, what are other tools to build search  functionality on top of MS SQL? This question is particularly for searching records, not files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I documented how I used Lucene.NET in my ASP.NET application BugTracker.NET here:

http://www.ifdefined.com/blog/post/2009/02/Full-Text-Search-in-ASPNET-using-LuceneNET.aspx

Answer (score 4):

In episode 11 of the SO podcast Jeff and Joel discussed full text searching of SQL Server, Joel's recommendation was [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/).  You can see their discussion in that episode's [transcript](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W12621), it is about a quarter of the way down the page.

Comment: This is about what I was going to comment; in FogBugz we use Lucene.NET for our full-text searches.  Keep in mind that Lucene wants to index your data before you can search it, and this takes a while on very large data sets.

Comment: All along I thought Lucene.NET is for document indexing.

Answer (score 2):

2008's [full text search capabilities](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721269.aspx) have been improved - perhaps look there first..

Comment: Will check this out along with compatibility with Entity Framework

Answer (score 1):

I believe MS SQL 2005+ has the capability to search using regular expression.

MSDN has an article about this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx.